# C++ writing a copy constructor for simple linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy-constructor

Trying to write a simple copy constructor for a linked list class. My class is simple, I have a variable First that points to the first node, and a variable Last that points to the last node.

It is single linked, so each node just points to the next one, there is no previous. Trying to write a copy constructor, but finding that the last node seems to be still pointing to the same address, such if I add something to the copied list, it shows up in the original one as well.

Heres what I have so far:

```
queue::queue(const queue &v){
    first = v.first;
    last = v.last;


    first-> value = v.first->value;

    node *curr = first;
    node *otherCur = v.first;
    while(otherCur->next != NULL){
        cout << "------Next is: " << otherCur->next->value << endl;
        curr ->next = otherCur->next;
        curr->next->value = otherCur->next->value;
        curr = curr->next;
        otherCur = otherCur->next;

    }
    curr->next = NULL;


}
```

Comment: All the nodes in the second object points to the same nodes in the first object. You need to allocate memory for the nodes of the second list and just copy the values from the nodes of the first list.

Comment: To restate, you're copying the pointers when you should be copying the pointed-to data

Answer (score 0):

You have not done any `node` allocation in your code. In fact each `node` should belong to only one `queue`. So by copying `v`, you should allocate as many `node` as there are in `v`.

Note that in the following code, the destructor of `queue` should delete all the created nodes.

```
queue::queue(const queue &v) : first(NULL), last(NULL) {
    if (v.first) {
        first = new node(*v.first);
        first->next = NULL;
        last = first;
        // first-> value = v.first->value; // copy constructor should have done that

        node *curr = first;
        node *otherCur = v.first;
        while(otherCur->next != NULL){
            cout << "------Next is: " << otherCur->next->value << endl;
            curr->next = new node(*otherCur->next);
            curr->next->next = NULL;
            last = curr->next;
            // curr->next->value = otherCur->next->value;
            curr = curr->next;
            otherCur = otherCur->next;
        }
        // curr->next = NULL;
    }
}
```